# phpMyAdmin Status Monitor is shown blank

Tags: phpmyadmin, monitor, status

When I try to open phpMyAdmin - Status - Monitor, there is nothing to see.
Nothing is showing there for a while. It seems just blank

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version?

Comment: This is an outdated version, but I don't remember seeing this bug on this old version. Please describe your server environment.

Comment: what do you mean by "server environment" ? My friend tested the phpMyAdmin - Status - Monitor of  my server in his own pc and he said that "it works fine"! does this problem is caused of my laptop? I tested monitor service on chrom and mozilla browsers in my laptop but that was the same

Comment: On your laptop, which OS, which web server, which MySQL server, which PHP version?

Comment: I use windows 10 in my laptop. The web server of my server is Apache/2.2.31, MySQL version is 5.6.27, PHP version is 5.4.45

Comment: Any chance you can update your phpMyAdmin?

Comment: yes I can if it's needed! I set the WHM to update PHPMyadmin automatically. If it's neede please help me update it

Comment: I'm not sure if the update will help you, but keep in mind that 4.0.10.7 is outdated.